# Как осуществить движение точки по заданному вектору?

Tags: python, математика, геометрия, вектор

Пытаюсь реализовать функцию движения объекта в 2D пространстве. Есть вектор AB, точка B которого привязана к местоположению объекта. Мы знаем направление вектора и его координаты. Как переместить объект по направлению вектора?

Пример: Имея вектор (0, 0), (1, 0.5) нужно переместиться на 0.1 единицу вперед по направлению. Не помешала бы формула, по которой можно это вычислить.

[image: Пример]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Пример: Имея вектор (0, 0), (1, 0.5) нужно переместиться на 0.1
> единицу вперед по направлению. Не помешала бы формула, по которой
> можно это вычислить.

вообще-то:
x = coord + vector

т.е.

```
x1 = x0 + vx
y1 = y0 + vy
```

У вас же совершенно непонятно как из вектора (1, 0.5) можно получить перемещение на 0.1 по оси x

Если же вы имели в виду, что из точки надо переместиться в сторону вектора на 0.1, то тогда формула

```
x1 = x0 + 0.1 * vx / size(vector)
y1 = y0 + 0.1 * vy / size(vector)
```

где

```
size(vector) = sqrt(vx*vx + vy*vy)
```

Comment: Да, я имел в виду именно перемещение по вектору на 0.1. Уточните пожалуйста, как указать в формуле vx и vy?  size - выходит, длина вектора, которая равна сумме квадратов под корнем. А что мы получаем при делении вектора на его длину? Единичный вектор?

Comment: Единичный вектор, сонаправленный с исходным